# Ltac not working after upgrading to Coq 8.5

Tags: coq, ltac

I have the following Ltac (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950479/how-to-automatically-introduce-symmetries-into-coq-hypotheses)), which used to work on Coq 8.4pl6, but it's not working on Coq 8.5 beta 3:

```
Ltac maybe_intro_sym A B :=
  match goal with
    |[H:B=A|-_] => fail 1
    |[H:A=B|-_] => assert (B=A) by auto
  end.

Ltac maybe_intro_sym_neg A B :=
  match goal with
    |[H:B<>A|-_] => fail 1
    |[H:A<>B|-_] => assert (B<>A) by auto
  end.

Ltac intro_sym :=
  repeat match goal with
    |[H:?A=?B|-_] => maybe_intro_sym A B
    |[H:?A<>?B|-_] => maybe_intro_sym_neg A B
end.
```

I got an error message saying

```
Error: The reference B was not found
in the current environment.
```

I don't know enough about Ltac. Can anyone help explain how to fix this?

Comment: There is no problem for me. Which of the three Ltac definitions sends this error  ?

Comment: @eponier It's the last one `intro_sym`.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not something stupid such as an unbreakable space after one of the `B` ?

Comment: Yes, it seems strange that it shouldn't work....  Have you copied and pasted it from the page?  Or could there be a missing '?' before the B in the pattern? (The pattern is what's before the '=>')  (Note that only intro_sym should have question marks, as it should match any _ = _ term, but the others shouldn't, as they should only match the specific term with the given A and B)

Comment: I have copy-and-pasted the above into a library file `SfLib.v` from described and available from https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/SfLib.html to be included in other `.v` files. This worked on Coq 8.4pl6 without a problem, but gave me the quoted error when 8.5beta3 is used. I am not sure if it could be a conflict with content in that file, but otherwise things are copy-pasted without missing a white space.

Comment: Ok, I have found what the problem is. `SfLib.v` requires `Arith`, and `Arith` defines the notation `=?` which is used here. Just add a space between `=` and `?B` and it will work.

Comment: @eponier, thanks, if you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coq 8.5, `Arith` defines the notation `=?`. Because of this, what was interpreted as `= ?B` is now interpreted as `=? B`. Adding a space between `=` and `?B` should be enough.